# Saving and loading times via php and displaying time on stage

Tags: actionscript-3

I have times saving from the end of a game at being uploaded onto my server via php and have been able to bring the times back and trace them.

My question is how do I put the data O trace...

```
trace (event.target.data);
```

Into a text field called TimeText?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather simple...

TimeText.text = String(event.target.data);